# Como fazer seletor de idiomas

Tags: javascript, css, html-select

Tenho um site e preciso colocar um seletor de idiomas nele, quando o usuário selecionar a bandeira correspondente ao idioma desejada ser redirecionado para uma url especifica.

```html
 <select>
   <option>Brazil</option>
   <option>English</option>
   <option>spanish</option>
</select>
```

No caso do exemplo do código acima ao invés dos nomes eu quero a bandeira dentro, já tentei inserir a imagem diretamente mas não aparece, e depois de selecionado ser redirecionado para uma URL mencionado, eu sei que é com javascript que fazz isso, só não sei como, alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `select` do HTML não suporta isso nativamente, você não consegue customizar o html interno do `select`

Para fazer o que você deseja são usados plugins que montam elementos que parecem `selects` e fazem a mesma coisa que os selects fazem porém sendo customizáveis, um deles é o [select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) que você pode ver funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deFreitas/15xh85Lf/) e [aqui vários outros exemplos de como usá-lo](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating)

Basicamente você monta um template para que o select2 loope

```
function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
  var $state = $(
    '<span><img src="bandeiras/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png" class="img-flag" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
  );
  return $state;
};

$(".meu-select").select2({
  templateResult: formatState
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Ao invés de usar a tag "select", podes utilizar como se fosse uma lista, resolveria o seu problema. Olhe abaixo:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://redirecionaparabandeira"><img src="imagemBandeira" /></a></li>
   ....
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [Flagstrap](https://github.com/blazeworx/flagstrap) que faz exatamente o que você deseja, ou ainda usar o [Countries dropdown with flags](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/countries-dropdown-flags) que também atende suas necessidades.